# Can't access 8000 port of a Django project in docker

Tags: django, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to put my Django project into a docker image.

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt -i https://pypi.douban.com/simple
ADD . /code/
EXPOSE 8000
```

Then I build and run this docker container:

```
docker run -i -t -p 8000:8000 e2 python3 manage.py runserver 8000
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 25, 2017 - 16:28:00
Django version 1.11.3, using settings 'chaoYuBackend.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

But when I visit `localhost:8000` or `127.0.0.1:8000` in Chrome, I got `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

This is what I got by executing `docker ps`, it seems that the 8000 port has been exposed:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
71c0502de704        e2                  "python3 manage.py..."   54 seconds ago      Up 52 seconds       0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp   gallant_boyd
```

When I run `lsof -i :8000`, I got an error:

[image: lsof result]

My docker version is `17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87`, and I'm using MacOS 10.12.6.

It's there anything wrong in my `Dockerfile`? How can I visit my Django site in browser?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `lsof -i :8000` check if 8000 is actually in use. use `sudo iptables-save` list your iptables rules.

Answer (score 2):

Change the building/running command of docker to:

```
docker run -i -t -p 8000:8000 e2 python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

The problem is that you haven't specified the listening host, so it's set directly to the loopback interface `127.0.0.1`, that's why it's just accessible just from the container itself.

So when you set the host to the broadcast address `0.0.0.0` it will be accessible for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I finally fix this problem!

I guess this is caused by the **homebrew docker package**.

After reinstalling docker via the official dmg, everything is alright.

Answer (score 0):

Docker exposes container ports on the random localhost ports. Look at `docker ps`:

```
PORTS
0.0.0.0:32769->8000/tcp
```

Docker exposes port `32769` on your local machine. You can get access by `localhost:32769`

Answer (score 0):

> The -P option publishes all the ports to the host interfaces. Docker binds each exposed port to a random port on the host. ...

replace '-P' with '-p 8000:8000' and try again.

Comment: Unbelievable, still ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED ? check proxy on your browser, and check port, process on your system. Run cmd 'curl http://localhost:8000/', and show your response here.

Comment: I got `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8000: Connection refused`